# java Conversion with com.jhlabs.map.proj from UTM SUMO Simulator coordinates to WGS84 lat/long

Tags: java

i try to make a program in java that convert the x,y coordinates UTM to WGS84 format latitude and longitude. I reach the UTM coordinates by an xml simulation file generated by SUMO simulator whith netconvert function passing an openstreetMap file .osm. The conversion output by the simulator gives me these parameters :
location netOffset="-496616.58,-4916305.46" convBoundary="0.00,0.00,392.25,326.77" origBoundary="8.957512,44.400028,8.962437,44.402970" 
projParameter="+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"/>

I 'm using a library com.jhlabs.map.proj that is a java implementation of proj4.dll that i found is the library c++ that the simulator used. So i want to do a dinamicaly inverse conversion from evry x/y coordinate to long/lat with this java library. (I have just tring also jcoord library but with no good result).
Using projParameters i do:

```
String[] proj4_w = new String[]{"+proj=utm",
              "+zone=32",
              "+ellps=WGS84",
             "+datum=WGS84",
            "+units=m",
            "+no_defs",

            "+to",
            "+proj=latlong",
            "+ellps=WGS84",
            "+datum=WGS84",
            "+no_defs"

            };

        Projection proj = ProjectionFactory.fromPROJ4Specification(proj4_w);

        Point2D.Double testUtm = new Point2D.Double(utmX(), utmY());
        Point2D.Double testProjec = proj.transform(testUtm, new Point2D.Double());

        System.out.println("latitudine: " + testProjec.x + " longitudine: " + stProjec.y);
```

the latitude and longitude value that i get from result are not correct value.
I'm newest from this type of problem and there is little documntation.
Thanks for every answer and every solution also with differt way or library.

Answer (score 0):

`com.jhlabs.map.proj` does not support this feature, if you wish, it is possible to use this fork: https://github.com/bdferris/onebusaway-jmapprojlib (Repository: http://nexus.onebusaway.org/content/groups/public/)

Uage example: https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-uk/blob/master/onebusaway-uk-atco-cif-parser/src/main/java/org/onebusaway/uk/atco_cif/AtcoCifParser.java#L285-L286